# Show that the system $Xw = y$ has infinitely many solutions if and only if $y\perp Ker(X^\top)$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $X$ be the design matrix of a linear regression problem with $m$ rows (samples) and $d$ columns (variables/features). Let $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$ be the response vector corresponding the samples in $X$.

Let $y=Xw$ be a non-homogeneuous system of linear equations.
Assume that $X$ is square and not invertible.
Show that the system has infinitely many solutions if and only if $y\perp Ker(X^\top)$.

---

I tried to prove it like that but I can't finish the proof :

Let $\textbf{y} = \textbf{X}\textbf{w}$ be a non-homogeneous system of linear equations, and we assume that $\textbf{X}$ is square and not invertible. We want to prove that the system has $\infty$ solution $\iff$ $\textbf{y}\perp Ker(\textbf{X}^\top)$.

$\Rightarrow$ Let's assume that the linear system $\textbf{X}\textbf{w} = \textbf{y}$ has infinitely many solutions (due to the invertibility of $\textbf{X}$). Because the matrix $\textbf{X}$ is not invertible, we know that $Ker(\textbf{X})$ is non-empty ($i.e.$ there exists a non-zero vector $\textbf{v}$ such that $\textbf{X}\textbf{v} = 0$). Since $\textbf{X}\textbf{v} = 0$, we have $\textbf{X}^\top\textbf{X}\textbf{v} = 0$, which implies that $\textbf{X}^\top \textbf{z} = 0$ ($i.e.$ $\textbf{z}\in Ker(\textbf{X}^\top)$), where $\textbf{z} = \textbf{X}\textbf{v}$. Finally,
$$\langle \textbf{y}, \textbf{z}\rangle  = \textbf{y}^\top \textbf{z} = \textbf{y}^\top \textbf{X}\textbf{v} = 0 \quad \textrm{because $\textbf{v}\in Ker(\textbf{X})$}$$
we have $\langle \textbf{y}, \textbf{z}\rangle  =\textbf{y}^\top \textbf{z} = 0$ whenever $\textbf{X}^\top \textbf{z} = 0$.
Then, $\textbf{y}$ is orthogonal to all vector $\textbf{z}\in Ker(\textbf{X}^\top)$, therefore, $\textbf{y}\perp Ker(\textbf{X}^\top)$.

$\Leftarrow$ ??

Also, I am not satisfied with the "$\Rightarrow$" part because I don't really use the fact that the system has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: If $y\perp Ker(X^\top)$, then $y\in Ker(X^\top)^\perp$. Then use $Im(X)=Ker(X^\top)^\perp$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's fix some issues in the $\Rightarrow$ direction.
First, look at this:

> Let's assume [...] (due to the invertibility of $X$).

The phrase inside the parenthesis should be removed.
You are assuming a condition is true.
It is not a deduction (and it does not make sense even if it is).

Next, you are asked to show that for *ALL* vector $z\in Ker(X^\top)$,
we have $\langle y,z \rangle=0$,
not just a single one.
The $z$ in your argument is a single vector defined by $z=Xv$.
You did not show that $y$ is orthogonal to all elements in $Ker(X^\top)$.

---

As said in my comment, use the fact that $Im(X)=Ker(X^\top)^\perp$.
Then $y\perp Ker(X^\top)$ is equivalent to $y\in Im(X)$.
You can then work from there.

Comment: Ok, so for the ⇒ part : Let's assume that the linear system $\textbf{X}\textbf{w} = \textbf{y}$ has infinitely many solutions, then $y \in Im(\textbf{X})$. But, using the following result : $ Im(A^\top) = Ker(A)^\perp$, thus we can write that $y\in Im(\textbf{X}) \iff y\in Ker(\textbf{X}^\top)^\perp$, and then $y\perp Ker(\textbf{X}^\top)$.

Comment: @isaac Yes, and you can do it for the converse as well, using the same fact.

Comment: Think about how you would get infinitely many solutions from just one particular solution.